# Mouse leave method is not working to hide content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have added mousehover and mouseleave functionality to nav-tabs, its showing content when I hover the icon but its not hiding the content when mouseleaves.

Even I tried to hide tab-content where ever i click on screen,Its worked.If i hover the icon again tab-content is not getting displayed.

can anyone help me to fix it?

-->If i hover/click the icon content should be displayed.

-->If hoverout/click anywhere on the screen tab-content should be hided ,again it should show the tab-content whenever i hover/click the icon.

Please help me to fix this guys.

```js
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).tab('show');
});
 $('.nav-tabs > li > a').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).tab('hide');
});


/*  $(document).click(function(){  
  $('#home').hide(); //hide the button

  });
  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"><i ng-click="clickevent()" class="fa fa-user-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade">      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>   
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">      
       <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>     
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">      
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>          
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">     
       <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>        
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You put your script in css section. Check your snippet again.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with [tag:angularjs] tag? It has nothing to do with angularjs

Answer (score 1):

there is no 'hide' in bootstrap tabs but you can overcome it by this code (simply reset the changes of bootstrap):

```
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').mouseleave(function () {
   $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
   var id = this.href.split('#')[1];
   $("#" + id).removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: i have some navigation link in tab-content,am unable to access it because of screen hide.

Comment: please suggest something to complete this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e1rqo04f/ here it is.Icon are not displaying in fiddle but its displaying in my page.

Comment: I don't see any link... can u tell me what do u mean?

Comment: can you see some <p></p> element in tab-content?I have replaced that paragraph content with some <href> elements in my original code. whenever i hover on the element tab-content will be displayed,then i should be able to access the tab-content .because of the code you have provided ,I can achieve the mouseleave functionality but I am unable to access the tab-content now.